# Weakly separated sets can be strongly separated implies complete normality.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to understand the proof that if any sets $A,B$ in $X$ such that $\overline{A}\cap B = B\cap \overline{A} = \emptyset$ can be separated by open sets, i.e., there are disjoint $U,V$ with $A\subset U$ and $B\subset V$, then $X$ is completely normal. I have seen [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280672/if-there-exist-disjoint-open-sets-containing-separated-sets-then-the-space-is-c) and also [this answer](http://www.austinmohr.com/Work_files/hw1-1.pdf), both of which assert that if $C,D$ are closed subsets of some subspace $Y$, then writing $C = C_x \cap Y$ and $D = D_x\cap Y$ for closed $C_x,D_x$ in $X$ then $C_x$ and $D_x$ are weakly separated. But this is not true! For example, in the subspace $Y = [-1,0)\cup (0,1]$ of $\mathbb{R}$, the sets $[-1,0)$ and $(0,1]$ are closed in $Y$ but no $C_x, D_x$ are weakly separated. How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the $C_x$ and $D_x$ to be weakly separated in $X$, you just use them to show that $A$ and $B$ are weakly separated in $X$.

In a bit more detail, let $C_x$ be the closure of $A$ in $X$ and $D_x$ be the closure of $B$ in $X$.  Then since $B \subseteq Y$ we have $C_x \cap B = (C_x \cap Y) \cap B = A \cap B = \emptyset$, and similarly $A \cap D_x = \emptyset$.  In your example, $C_x = [-1, 0]$ and $D_x = [0, 1]$.  They aren't weakly separated, but that's not relevant - they are only used to show that $[-1, 0)$ and $(0, 1]$ are weakly separated in $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are weakly separated in $X$ you get open sets $U, V \subseteq X$ such that $A \subseteq U$, $B \subseteq V$, and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.  Then $U \cap Y$ and $V \cap Y$ are disjoint open sets in $Y$ that separate $A$ and $B$.